# Vue Props data not reflecting to child component as it's changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Hi I am having a problem with vue props in. as I am passing a prop and it's data is changing but that change is not reflecting to child component until i change some other data. Attaching vue dev-tool screenshot[image]

As in the image language value is changed but that change has not been reflected to Ui or child component in the left.

Is this because of one way flow rule for props :thinking_face

Comment: How you declare props? Show specific children and parent component

Comment: Please update the snippet and we can convenient to solve your problem.

Comment: maybe your select component is not reactive